# Cursor visually in place, but functionally not

Tags: cursor, tinymce

My cursor is right where it needs to be in my text editor - visually. When I continue typing from the keyboard - nothing is shown. The cursor is in the browser (when I press up-down arrow keys from the keyboard - the browser page is moved up/down). I need to click on the text editor so that I can continue typing. Even though the cursor is visible and blinking in the text editor. I use tinymce and ie9. (I use ie9 just for testing purposes, I'm not crazy).

When I execute:

```
document.activeElement
```

it returns that an iframe element has focus, and not the text area.

Comment: You on gmail? Gmail may have info about why. The same error occurs in gmail on ie8 in their search box. They recommend upgrading your browser. Ouch.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 I use ie9. And no, it doesn't concern gmail.

Comment: Well, a lot of users fix this in gmail by turning off compatibility mode for the domain that is affected. If that works, you can hone in on the problem more. Meanwhile, your tinymce version would maybe help.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 tinymce version 3.4.8

Comment: Can you update to latest? There are similar questions with accepted answers which advise an update.